# Which plugin is best for left and right swipe in mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile

I want to implement swipe functionality in mobile view of my site. I have searched but didn't find any plugin that is working according to my expectation. most of the plugins are not smooth.
Should I create my own swiping plugin or is there any smooth plugin already available in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend to use [swiper-master](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/).
you can find the github repository at [github](https://github.com/powerfinger/swiper-master)

here is the demo [demo](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos.php)

hope this will help you.